# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed, opencv

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, opencv

Trying to get `node-opencv` working and I'm hitting some errors that I cannot decipher. Any helpful insight is much appreciated.

This happens anytime I try to run one of the examples. In my own attempts I can create a `cv.VideoStream(0)` but once I try to create an object detection stream or read from the camera it throws the same error.

```
[~/opencvtest/node_modules/opencv/examples] node camera

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2cv7imwriteERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS0_6vectorIiNS4_IiEEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/moog/opencvtest/node_modules/opencv/build/Release/opencv.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2cv7imwriteERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS0_6vectorIiNS4_IiEEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/moog/opencvtest/node_modules/opencv/build/Release/opencv.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've tried reinstalling OpenCV and rebuilding `node-opencv` but I hit the same error.

```
node-opencv: v0.5.0
opencv: v2.4.9
node.js: v0.10.28
osx: v10.9.3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this problem by the following steps:

1. delete all opencv things.... like `brew uninstall opencv`
2. reinstall opencv by brew again and add echos like

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv@3/bin:$PATH"
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/opencv@3/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/opencv@3/include"
   ```

   where opencv@3 is my opencv version to your .bash_profile
3. link opencv with `brew link --overwrite --force opencv@3`.

My problem is that I didn't delete my old opencv files clean so I need to `brew link --force`

Wish I can help.